# mightybigrobot profile:Edit forms are not valid html

Tags: profile-edit, validation, mightybigrobot

I have lots of unescaped ampersands in this form. How can I fix this so I can validate my page as html5

Comment: Ate you serious man. Take a step back and read your post - it don't explain anything.

Comment: ok so it is not a great description, however will not take a lecture from someone who uses the phrase "it don't explain anything" if you were looking for the contracted form of "does not" the word is "doesn't".

Comment: Anyway it is a simple thing the profile:Edit module from big mighty robot doesn't (see what I did there) validate. Can I make it pass the validator by escaping the ampersands.

Comment: Lol, I be educated. My grammar is the least of your issues. BOL.

Comment: What specific tags are you referring to? Can you post a code example of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer would be to go through the add-on code and replace any ampersands with html entities but I'm guessing you've already tried that?

I don't think there will be a quick way to do it other than doing that.

I would say that you really don't need to worry about it. Validation is a guide, not a requirement. Especially at this level. Are you experiencing problems with the forms? If they work, don't worry about it. They will continue to do so until we're all old and grey.